# Django change url from http:\/\/ to http://

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a response from an API that formats URLs like: `http:\/\/domain.com\/`. How do I make them normal URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do:

```
url.replace('\/', '/')
```

There isn't anything built-in, but leaving it as an exercise for you to turn this into a custom template filter. [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) are pretty good.

Comment: Yea, I just didn't know if there was a way to do it in the template tag, so I dont have to parse through the dict before displaying it

Comment: @Brenden: Your best bet is to write a custom template tag to do that for you.

Comment: Why is this API being called from the template? If possible, I'd do this in the view in python.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The API is being called in the view, and the response is being passed to the template. If I can fix in the template, I dont have to do a for loop over the response to change the URL

Comment: I build a custom template tag. Thanks!

Comment: @Brenden, if it's being called in the view, I'd definitely try to make these modifications in the view. Building a tag, adding new files, spreading code around seems like a lot of organizational overhead just to make a simple python change. But you may have your reasons - good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Use the [safe](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L450) filter as a guide on how to write your own that does this.